HttpListener in .NET 8 Docker Container Not Accessible Externally
I have a .NET 8 application that uses HttpListener and runs inside a Docker container. The Docker image I'm using is mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0.
Here's the issue I'm encountering:
When I configure HttpListener to use http://localhost:1234, everything works as expected, but the application is only accessible from within the same machine (i.e., I can't access it from another machine on the network).
When I try to use http://+:1234 to make the application accessible from any network interface, I get an exception and the HttpListener fails to start.
In a Windows environment, I can solve this issue by running the application as an administrator. However, I'm not sure how to achieve the same effect when running the application in a Docker container.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:
1.Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 1234
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "YourApp.dll"]

2.Running the container:
I use the following command to run the Docker container:
docker run -d -p 1234:1234 your-docker-image

3.HttpListener Configuration:
var listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:1234/");
listener.Start();

Despite these steps, the application fails to start with the http://+:1234 prefix. I suspect it might be a permissions issue since it works when running as an administrator on Windows.
Questions:
How can I grant the necessary permissions to HttpListener in a Docker container to bind to all network interfaces (http://+:1234)?
Are there any specific Docker configurations or best practices to achieve this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Can you access it from within the container?

I don't think it's a permission issue. Your container runs as root and port 1234 isn't a privileged port. If you do docker ps -a you should be able to see the failed container. Then you can do docker logs <container name> to the see logs and any error messages. Hopefully that'll tell you why it fails to start.

Do you try run docker command with sudo?

yes i can access it from the container
